# Is it possible to catch net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-chrome

So on our site we have various searches some of which work fine and return the appropriate results. A few of them however return the javascript error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT when I search on
>   my machine.

I have found out that issue is that I am running AdBlocker in Google Chrome and it is AdBlocker that is causing the problem. Now I know I could just turn AdBlocker off which is fine and I have, but is there a way for me to catch this error in javascript and report to the user why they are not getting any search results?

Ideally I am after something similar to a c# try/catch.

EDIT:
OK, so after some digging around and being pointed in the right direction from the comments below I think I have deduced the issue, hopefully this will help others.

After having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748315/getjson-fail-not-firing) it looks like what I am trying to accomplish cannot be done using the version of jQuery we are currently running (1.10.x) so I guess the solution is to use a new version of jQuery (2.x) and see if I can catch the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277656/how-to-handle-the-err-blocked-by-client-using-javascript

As this occurs with network requests, you can detect a failure if it's an XHR. If it's an asset then it's a bit more difficult. This is Chrome blocking some request by instruction.

Comment: So it's not strictly XHR, it's using $.getJSON() to send the request and retrieve the results. I had a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740218/error-handling-in-getjson-calls
And it looks like I am going to have to change how the request is sent...

Comment: But that link shows that you can handle errors (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5553540/966338) with `.error(function() { alert("error"); })`.. Does that not work for you in this case?

Comment: If you're looking to catch that error specifically from within the browser - unfortunately it's not going to be possible. You'll only ever get a **generic error message**.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have tried `.error(function() { alert('error'); });` and `.onerror(function() { alert('error'); });`

Both return the javascript error not a function

Comment: @PerryMitchell Actually `.error(function() { });` does not return a javascript error but the alert does not fire

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but what might help is detecting when offline and then not making requests until online: `window.addEventListener("offline", () => { console.log("on no, offline!") });`

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but I was surprised to find out that bug notification systems like Bugsnag and Sentry are blocked by Ad Blockers like uBlock Origin, etc. That sucks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot catch that error message specifically, but you can catch the error itself:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://openx.net',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function( data ) {
    console.log( "Success:", data);
  },
  error: function( data ) {
    console.log( "Error:", data);
  }
});
```

[image: Chrome blocking ad call]

> Obviously the example isn't requesting JSON, but you can see that it fails and calls the error handler.

These errors are fired by Chrome when, for instance, a plugin like Adblock (as you mentioned) cancels a request.

Comment: I have tried this but I don't get anything output to the console:

`$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                       //do stuff
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log("Error:", err);
            }
        });`

Comment: I've got it working with [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/hafunepoxa/edit?js,output). Make sure ad block is on, and the error will appear in the console.

Comment: I am gunna mark this as answered as your link works for me, I am clearly missing something in my code hopefully I will find out what it is! Thank you though!

Comment: Please note: this won't work with jQuery 1.x : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159558/how-detect-handle-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-jquery-1-x

Comment: **net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** is different, not work a console response.

Comment: @KingRider My example specifically shows ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT - I didn't mention ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT at all, and can't say if it'd ever work for that specific error.

Answer (score 0):

*For those like to me trying to get around it....

If you have any Ad Blockers, disable them for the URL.

Comment: Question is about how to catch this error, not avoid it.