# How detect/handle net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with jQuery 1.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect content blocker (ad-blocking extensions, hosts-based blocks, proxy-based blockades) with a simple script such as this:

```
try {

    $.ajax({
        url: '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js',
        dataType: 'jsonp',

        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
          alert(jqXHR.status);
        },

        always: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
          alert("always handler fired");
        }
    });

} catch(ex) {

    alert("ex cought");
}
```

[This works as expected with jQuery 3.x](https://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/6yjmyg9k/3/), but [it fails silently with jQuery 1.x](https://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/6yjmyg9k/2/) (please visit the two examples with an adblock extension enabled)

My application is stuck with jQuery 1.11.0 and I cannot upgrade it. Any ideas to trap `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` with jQuery 1.11.0?

Note: I cannot rely neither on `adsbygoogle.loaded`, nor on checking the banners visibility

Comment: Even with jquery 3.0 I cannot see how you can get net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Try this with jquery 1.
$.get('<url>').then(function(){//success, no adblock}), function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {//failed adblock or cross domain request})