# How should I fail gracefully when ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a call to a geolocation API:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp'
})
.done(function(location) {
  console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
  console.log("complete");
});
```

adblockers appear to block this, and I get the error `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` when adblocker is enabled. The problem is, it doesn't trigger either of the `.done`, `.fail` or `.always` handlers. I'm wondering if there's a solution that will trigger on `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` so that I can fail gracefully.

I could always execute a piece of code to see if a value was set after say 5 seconds, but I'd like something more complete.

Console screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Show us the console tab screenshot?

Comment: Done - uploaded

Comment: I take it the `done()` handler is triggered, so is there anything passed into that that would help?

Comment: Nope, nothing gets triggered

Comment: you may try to put your code in a `try/catch`

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527328/is-it-possible-to-catch-neterr-blocked-by-client might be the more appropriate duplicate here.

Comment: @CBroe This wont work because of jsonp.

Comment: @CBroe yes - that seemed to work, updating jQuery to version 3