# Detect if unhandled rejection is due to adblock

Tags: javascript, fetch, adblock

I am writing an unhandled Promise rejection handler. Within the handler, I want to be able to tell if the rejection is caused by the client blocking a fetch request, via adblock or etc.

With adblock enabled, if you try to fetch `"https://ad.doubleclick.net"`, it shows `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` in the console:

[image: screenshot of Chrome DevTools console showing GET https://ad.doubleclick.net/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT]

But when that bubbles out to `window.onunhandledrejection`, there's no way to tell that that's why the Promise was rejected; the error message says "TypeError: failed to fetch", but that's pretty vague.

[image: screenshot of Chrome DevTools showing the properties on a PromiseRejectionEvent]

Is there a way to detect that the error is due to adblock?

Comment: you need to pass response message into callback rejection and then parse response status/code.

Comment: there's no response, since the Promise is rejected.

Comment: could you share a code with request?

Comment: This is a copy of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527328/is-it-possible-to-catch-neterr-blocked-by-client